# What is the difference between bzr lp-propose and bzr lp-propose-merge?

Tags: command-line, application-development, programming, launchpad, bazaar

What is the difference between `bzr lp-propose` and `bzr lp-propose-merge`?

Do I have to provide the branch I wish to propose a merge to, or does it assume it for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bzr lp-propose` and `bzr lp-propose-merge` are the same command (`lp-propose` being an alias of  `lp-propose-merge`):

```
$ bzr lp-propose --help
Purpose: Propose merging a branch on Launchpad.
Usage:   bzr lp-propose-merge [SUBMIT_BRANCH]

Options:
  --staging             Propose the merge on staging.
  -v, --verbose         Display more information.
  -R ARG, --review=ARG  Requested reviewer and optional type.
  --fixes=ARG           The bug this proposal fixes.
  -q, --quiet           Only display errors and warnings.
  --usage               Show usage message and options.
  -m ARG, --message=ARG
                        Commit message.
  --approve             Mark the proposal as approved immediately, setting the
                        approved revision to tip.
  -h, --help            Show help message.

Description:
  This will open your usual editor to provide the initial comment.  When it
  has created the proposal, it will open it in your default web browser.

  The branch will be proposed to merge into SUBMIT_BRANCH.  If SUBMIT_BRANCH
  is not supplied, the remembered submit branch will be used.  If no submit
  branch is remembered, the development focus will be used.

  By default, the SUBMIT_BRANCH's review team will be requested to review
  the merge proposal.  This can be overriden by specifying --review (-R).
  The parameter the launchpad account name of the desired reviewer.  This
  may optionally be followed by '=' and the review type.  For example:

    bzr lp-propose-merge --review jrandom --review review-team=qa

  This will propose a merge,  request "jrandom" to perform a review of
  unspecified type, and request "review-team" to perform a "qa" review.

Aliases:  lp-submit, lp-propose
From:     plugin "launchpad"
```